# How to display JSON data in an html element using redux-thunk store

Tags: json, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I am trying to use Redux and redux-thunk middleware to modify state change and make use of async actions to send data and receive data from the server. I created my own rails api which is returning the JSON data in the console.log of my webpage but Im wondering how to render this data in a div in my html. I realize this may not be coded in the best way, any help with re-writing would be appreciated too!

Here is the start of my app.js file

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import "./assets/style.css";
import Quiz from "./components/quiz"
import Home from "./components/home";
import Result from "./components/Result";
import { useEffect } from "react";



function App() {

 useEffect (() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/questions")
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(console.log);
     },[])
  return (
<div className="App">
      <Router>
      <Switch >
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
         { <Route exact path="/quiz">
           <Quiz/>
        </Route>}
        <Route exact path="/result">
          <Result />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import quizReducer from './store/reducers/reducer'
import "./assets/style.css";
import App from "./App";


const store = createStore(quizReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Here are my action/reducer

actions.js

```
export const getQuestion = (question) => ({type: "GOT_QUIZ", payload: question})

export const fetchQuestion = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(url)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(question => {
            dispatch(getQuestion(question))
        })
    }
}

export const createQuestion = (question) => {
    return () => {
        const configObj = {
            method: 'POST',
            question: JSON.stringify(question)
        }

        fetch(url, configObj)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json)
        })
    }
}
```

reducer.js

```
export default function quizReducer(state = {questionBank: []}, action){
    switch (action.type){

        case "GOT_QUIZ":
            return {...state, questionBank: action.payload}

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but normally you juste have to get your state with ```store.getState()``` and then you can expose the returned state components (for example ```state.questionBank```)

Comment: in the useEffect hook?

Comment: Yes you can do it in there, what I like to do is wrapping my ```store.getState()``` in a function so if I need to modify some data it's clean

Comment: is it better to write it in the reducer?

Comment: I didn't see an article talking about this, but I usually create a ```store.js``` file in which I put every function that I'll be using in my app, so I never call the ```store``` directly

Comment: i have a store folder which has an action folder and a reducer folder and the files in there. I am just having trouble with displaying the json data in an html div and i am not sure how to code that

Comment: If your are not sure, you can just use ```const state = store.getState()``` and then ```const questionBank = state.questionBank``` in your ```useEffect``` for example, that'll do the trick !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your reducer and actions are correct, you need to do two things in your components.

#### 1) Initialize the Fetch

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchQuestion} from './actions';
```

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect (() => {
    dispatch(fetchQuestion());
}, []);
```

This will call your `fetchQuestions` thunk once when the component is first mounted.

#### 2) Access the Data

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
```

```
const questions = useSelector(state => state.questionBank);
```

This will access the array of questions from your store and automatically respond to changes when the store state is updated.

Perhaps step 1 goes in `App` and step 2 goes in `Quiz` and `Result`.  Or perhaps both steps go in `App` and you pass down the data through props.

Comment: Thank you! I also believe I have an issue with my mapStateToProps, i currently have ```const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
      state}} ``` I am not sure how to code this to access the store

Comment: You don’t need mapStateToProps or connect if you are using the hooks (useSelector and useDispatch). It’s an either/or situation.  Any component that’s inside of the Provider will be able to access your store instance with the hooks.

Comment: thank you for all the help! Ive reworked my action/reducer but i think I have my redux/store set up wrong, I still cant get the json to display in the DOM(but its in the console.log).